# Private connection between Windows Server

Tags: networking

I have two Windows Server 2012 R2, they have 2 NICs each one! One for Public netw. and another for Private.

I need to daily transfer data from Server A to Server B and would like to do it via the Private NIC so not to bother the public network.

I have assigned Private IP to Server A: 192.168.10.10 and Server B: 192.168.10.20
No Default Gateway as I have assigned the GW to Public NIC.

Might the route add cmd would help but need your assistance so once data travel from Server A to B and vice versa to use only the private NIC.

Thank you!

Comment: Send the files to the local IP address?

Comment: I do not understand, how to send the data to local add?

Comment: How do you currently transfer files between them?  You can setup a network share.  You can setup FTP functionality.   Give us something to work with.

Comment: I use network share

Comment: Well, use the network share then. You already have a solution

Comment: my problem is not how to transfer data:) but how to use only the Private NIC for the connection between these two servers and Public NIC for any other connections

Comment: How do you access the servers from each other? By name or by ip address?

Comment: by ip address, also i edited hosts file so resolve based on prv ip

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On both servers:

1. Edit the hosts files so the names of servers are resolved to "private" IP addresses.
2. Enable Firewall and create 2 rules (inbound and outbound):

   - a rule that denies any traffic originated from "public" IP address of server A with destinantion of "public" IP address of server B;
   - a rule that denies any traffic originated from "public" IP address of server B with destinantion of "public" IP address of server A.
3. If any network services are left, that use "public" IP addresses, will stop working until you config them to use "private" IP addresses.

Answer (score -1):

While the previous answer can work, it cannot be considered a best practice as it hinders traffic from the traversing the public interfaces in the event it is desired/required.

I recently completed a small 3 node virtualization cluster utilizing 1Gbps interfaces for cluster/public traffic and 10Gbps interfaces strictly for the iSCSI SAN traffic.

To allow the 3 nodes to continue to communicate with each other across the public network and isolate the iSCSI traffic to the 10G network (exp: 10.20.20.0/24) Static routes were added to each node to specify that the iSCSI traffic only transverse the 10G interfaces, leaving the 1G interfaces for all other traffic.

Here’s an example of the PowerShell syntax used to add static routes for the 10G (dual interface) network.

```
New-NetRoute –DestinationPrefix "10.20.20.20/24" –InterfaceIndex 1 –NextHop 10.20.20.201 -RouteMetric 1
New-NetRoute –DestinationPrefix "10.20.20.20/24" –InterfaceIndex 2 –NextHop 10.20.20.201 -RouteMetric 1
```

The following link outlines the New-Route PowerShell command:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826148.aspx